# I got NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm going back to OOP in java. Here I got problem with simple example:

```
class CreateString {
    private String name;

    public CreateString(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String string = new String(name);//AAA
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateString myName = new CreateString("tomjas");
    }
}
```

I got NullPointerException from line denoted as "AAA". When I change the second line into

```
 private String name="";
```

it's ok. What is wrong with that code? I thought that field is initialised as one could conclude from constructor. Any hints and pointers to documentation?

Comment: @LutzHorn so it is a field with an initializator....

Comment: Running through in a debugger is excellent for spotting these order of operation problems

Answer (score 6):

Your `string` variable is a class attribute. Therefore it will be initialized when your class instance is created. But at that time `name` is still null, as you only assign a value to `name` in the constructor. So you end up with a NullPointerException.

To fix it, move `string = new String(name);` into the constructor:

```
class CreateString {
  private String name = null;
  private String string = null;

  public CreateString(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      string = new String(name);
  }
}
```

As the constructor is only executed after all the attributes have been initialized, it doesn't matter where you put the line `private String string;`. You could also place it after the constructor (as you did), and it would still be fine.

Answer (score 4):

All the fields are initialised before the constructor, as such when the line initialising `string` runs `name` is still null

```
class CreateString {
    private String name; //<--runs first

    public CreateString(String name) { //<--runs third
        this.name = name;
    }

    String string = new String(name);//AAA <---runs second
}
```

You could move the `string` initialisation within the constructor to solve this

```
class CreateString {
    private String name;
    String String string;

    public CreateString(String name) {
        this.name = name;
         string;= new String(name);//AAA 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = new String(name);//AAA
```

That line is in initializer block.So the default value is `null`, Since you are using it before assigning some value. Move that line to constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have any base class defined for your class, the order of execution would be :

1. initialize member fields of this class.
2. run the constructor of this class.

Since while executing this
`String string = new String(name);//AAA`                 since it executes first.
the variable `name` is still `null`. That's why it throws `NullPointerException`